# Object deallocated in ARC mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, automatic-ref-counting

The object is deallocated in ARC mode and causes crash. My code below;

```
BlockAlertView* alert = [BlockAlertView alertWithTitle:title message:message];
[alert setCancelButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"No", @"No Button") block:nil];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Yes", @"Yes Button") block:^{
        //Do Something
}];
[alert show];
```

It appears the correct alert view(which is custom UIView) but when I click one of the button it crashes.

The crash log;

`2015-04-07 22:28:17.065 Test[3213:781570] <BlockAlertView: 0x16bb4160> 
2015-04-07 22:33:01.746 Test[3213:781570] *** -[BlockAlertView performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x16bb4160`

Here is the source code of BlockAlertView;

[BlockAlertView on Github](https://github.com/vichevstefan/BlockAlertView)

For now I can't estimate any of the clues for this and makes me old.
Any input will be much appreciated!

Comment: What is `BlockAlertView` ? Show the code for it.

Comment: It's the one I have written and relatively long. not sure how to show you and even it is there, can it be the reason for deallocate?

Comment: Of course, creating and calling `show` in and of itself is no reason for the `alert` to be retained...

Comment: We definitely need to see BlockAlertView. I'm also especially interested in seeing where the delegate is being set because that will cause this error pretty reliably if it doesn't stick around long enough.

Comment: I declare it as class property strong and the crash has gone but I want to keep my current code. where can I post code? it's long

Comment: @vichevstefan For starters, post your `-show` method implementation.  Ideally,  `BlockAlertView` would keep itself alive long enough to do whatever it needs to do.

Comment: I have commit the source code of BlockAlertView to github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, that code worked correctly before it was converted to ARC.

To fix it, you'll need to create a strong reference to `self` in the `-show` method, and release this reference in `-dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` (where you see `[self autorelease]` commented out).

You can do this with a simple instance variable:

```
id _selfReference;
```

Assign `self` to `_selfReference` in `-show`:

```
- (void)show
{
    _selfReference = self;
    ...
```

and then set `_selfReference` to nil in `-dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` in the two places where you see `[self autorelease]` commented out.

Comment: That's correct, it has worked before converted to ARC

Answer (score 1):

Assign your `alert` object to live somewhere beyond your current function. One simple possibility is to just make it an instance variable. If that's not practical, create an instance `NSMutableArray *retainedItems;` which you allocate/init, and stuff this into.

Comment: Your answer seems reasonable, and I figured out to declare it as strong property of the class which is not ideal method to solve this but anyway bug has gone

Comment: Of course, remember to set the property to `nil` once you're done with it, so the object can be cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a design flaw in that project. The class is poorly named `BlockAlertView` as it's not actually a subclass of `UIView`. If it were a view and it was added to the view hierarchy then the view hierarchy would ensure it stayed alive whilst being viewed. As it is the view is kept alive but the object that created the view `BlockAlertView` is not held onto by anything and by the time the actions are called `BlockAlertView` is long gone.

This will require you to keep a `strong` ivar around to reference this "controller" object and it would be sensible to `nil` out that ivar in the completion blocks.

```
BlockAlertView *alertController = [BlockAlertView alertWithTitle:title message:message]; {
  [alertController setCancelButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"No", @"No Button") block:nil];

  __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
  [alertController addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Yes", @"Yes Button") block:^{
    //Do Something
    weakSelf.alertController = nil;
  }];

  [alertController show];
}

self.alertController = alertController;
```